# How can I connect to an open WiFi?

Tags: wifi

I was wondering how to connect to an open WiFi. The following command doesn't work. Sorry I can only take photo at this moment. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy & paste the command and output, e.g by using a removable USB pendrive to transfer the data to a computer with internet connection. What exactly means *"doesn't work"*? What OS and version do you use?

Answer (score 3):

```
wpa_passphrase "TP-LINK_BEAF" "" | sudo wpa_supplicant -D nl80211,wext -i wlp5s0 -c /dev/stdin
```

The first part of the pipeline, `wpa_passphrase "TP-LINK_BEAF" ""` is not correct: it only produces the `Passphrase must be 8..63 characters` error message and will not pass any output into the pipeline.

Since the second part of the pipeline is `sudo wpa_supplicant ... -c /dev/stdin`, you are effectively starting `wpa_supplicant` with an empty configuration. That is not going to work.

For an open network, you will need a configuration block like:

```
network={
        ssid="TP-LINK_BEAF"
        key_mgmt=NONE
}
```

Just write that into any file, e.g. `/etc/wpa_supplicant/TP-LINK_BEAF.conf`, and then invoke `wpa_supplicant` with:

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -D nl80211,wext -i wlp5s0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/TP-LINK_BEAF.conf
```